# What was Aditi's role with the symbol?

Tags: anjaan-special-crimes-unit

In the final episode of *Anjaan: Special Crimes Unit*, Vaidji insists that Aditi needs to hurry and bring Vikrant the fifth symbol so that he has a chance to defeat Vanraj, seemingly implying that it's essential for her to do this.

However, when Aditi gets there, the first four symbols are already active, without her having to uncover them.

> The final symbol forms in the stars, apparently spontanteously, and then it interacts with the four on the ground, producing a light that disables Vanraj's powers, and a portal that presumably sucks him back to whatever dimension he came from.

So far as I can tell, Aditi's actions didn't make a difference to this cosmic alignment. Why was it so urgent that she get there?

Comment: I know we're not supposed to say it, but the answer is "terrible writing"

Comment: @Valorum - You watched the show, or you are just guessing?

Comment: I've only seen the first few episodes (subtitled), but it didn't strike me as something with a strong and consistent mythos. It's more just "*monster of the week, random stuff that happens, forget about it by next week*" fodder, aping shows like the X-Files

Comment: @Valorum - Very much so. It's a supernatural police procedual, like many out there, where they mostly focus on investigating malicious ghosts across the country, with the occasional person with dangerous powers thrown in. However, Vanraj was supposed to be the unifying arc for the season, and was the focus of the first four or so episodes, so I would have thought they might have put a bit more thought into him.